How to group rows in dataset by two timestamps rage sizes?
I have a dataframe with two timestamps:
timestamp1             timestamp2
2022-02-18            2023-01-02    
2022-02-19            2023-01-04    
2022-02-21            2023-01-11    
2022-03-11            2024-02-05    
2022-03-12            2024-02-06    
2022-03-30            2024-02-07        

i want to group them (create new parameter group) by timestamps ranges. in each timestamp per group range of dates must not exceed a 4 days (so difference between max and min within group must be no higher than 4 days). so dessired result can be like:
timestamp1             timestamp2       group
2022-02-18            2023-01-02            1
2022-02-19            2023-01-04            1
2022-02-21            2023-01-11            2
2022-03-11            2024-02-05            3
2022-03-12            2024-02-06            3
2022-03-30            2024-02-07            4

as you see third row doesnt have group 1 because timestamp2 is 2023-01-11 (9 days larger than smallest timestamp2 in group 1). and last row is not in group 3 since its timestamp1 is 19 days larger than min timestamp1 in group 1
The goal is two have as many rows per group as possible with constraints mentioned before
How to do that? I tried this but it doesnt give desired results especially on larger dataset:
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'timestamp1': ['2022-02-18', '2022-02-19', '2022-02-21', '2022-03-11', '2022-03-12', '2022-03-30'],
    'timestamp2': ['2023-01-02', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-11', '2024-02-05', '2024-02-06', '2024-02-07']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['timestamp1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp1'])
df['timestamp2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp2'])

# Function to assign groups
def assign_groups(df):
    groups = []
    current_group = 1
    start_timestamp2 = df.iloc[0]['timestamp2']
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if (row['timestamp2'] - start_timestamp2).days > 4:
            current_group += 1
            start_timestamp2 = row['timestamp2']
        groups.append(current_group)
    return groups

# Assign groups
df['group'] = assign_groups(df)


Your approach is only considering the differences between consecutive timestamp2 values. To satisfy the constraint, you need to check the difference between the current row's timestamp1 and the minimum timestamp1 within the group as well.
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'timestamp1': ['2022-02-18', '2022-02-19', '2022-02-21', '2022-03-11', '2022-03-12', '2022-03-30'],
    'timestamp2': ['2023-01-02', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-11', '2024-02-05', '2024-02-06', '2024-02-07']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['timestamp1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp1'])
df['timestamp2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp2'])

# Function to assign groups
def assign_groups(df):
    groups = []
    current_group = 1
    start_timestamp2 = df.iloc[0]['timestamp2']
    start_timestamp1 = df.iloc[0]['timestamp1']
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if (row['timestamp2'] - start_timestamp2).days > 4 or (row['timestamp1'] - start_timestamp1).days > 4:
            current_group += 1
            start_timestamp2 = row['timestamp2']
            start_timestamp1 = row['timestamp1']
        groups.append(current_group)
    return groups

# Assign groups
df['group'] = assign_groups(df)

print(df)

